# Problems in JavaScript and PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a problem that I don't understand.

This is my JavaScript file exists in the js directory (part of the code):

```
    // This function will iterate over markersData array
    // creating markers with createMarker function
    function displayMarkers(){

   // this variable sets the map bounds according to markers position
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

   // for loop traverses markersData array calling createMarker function for 
     each marker 
     $.get("http://localhost/innotech/inc/get_data_google_api.php", 
     function(response) { 
       markersData = JSON.parse(response);
      //console.log(response);
```

This is my get_data_google_api.php file, in (inc) directory (part of the code)

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "123456";
    $dbname = "rythmstu_innotec";
     // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     // Check connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

     $return_arr = Array();

     $sql ="select * from records";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     array_push($return_arr,$row);
      }

      echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

I don't know why when I test it with `select * from records` (`records` is the table which contains all information). I doesn't show me any information in `http://localhost/innotech/inc/get_data_google_api.php` so the map will be empty.

But when I test it with for example `select * from records WHERE id=6784 or id=6786 or id=6788 or id=6782` It shows me those id in `http://localhost/innotech/inc/get_data_google_api.php` and also in the map (just those id, not all data)

I want to know why `select * from records` doesn't work.

Comment: why would you want to return all records *for each marker* ... why not just return the record for that marker (assuming there's some relationship between marker and record) -alternatively, get all records *once* ... and do some majick in javascipt to get the right record for each marker (though, I do understand you have a problem with getting all the records)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you have any bad data on your table. I'm trying copy and test your code and it's OK. Check the data into the table and say something more.

Another tip, are you close the right bracket and parentesis at the end of the javascript function?

HTML

```
$.get("./test.php", 
        function(response) { 
            markersData = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(markersData);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Only for say him that  his code is ok, perhaps his data make the error. One change: right bracket and parentesis on the javascript get function

Comment: that's fair enough